# Alert user via Error Tool Window if Build fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-extensions

I am building a Visual Studio Extension where I programmatically build a project using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Build(). If the build fails, I would like to alert the user by displaying the "Error List" tool window-similar to what happens when the user sees when he/she rebuilds a solution through VS when there is a compile error. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the `Error` task within you project file to programmatically raise errors (on the other hand build errors will be shown automatically in the Error list- and Output window; see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx

Comment: To trigger a build from an extension you could follow this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee891675.aspx; guess this is the recommended way instead of using the `MSBuild` evaluation stuff; since it involves the build logging, you should see any build errors and warnings in the error list window...